# Backup does not work on Ubuntu 16.10 and 16.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I enabled the built-in Backup feature in Ubuntu 16.10, but it doesn't work.
I get this error:

> Failed to execute child process "duplicity" (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1641423

Duplicity is not installed. Executing

```
sudo apt-get install duplicity
```

will fix that.

Comment: Be aware that apt-get gives you version 0.7.06 of duplicity on Ubuntu 16.04/16.10. This version has an issue that can cause your backups not to run. For details see https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1320641. 

I believe the answer given here is still correct. (An alternative would be to install duplicity outside of apt-get, which has its risks as well.) Just given the possible impact of this bug I thought it's good to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Had to install duplicity following python-gi

```
sudo apt-get install duplicity
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python-gi
```